# How to get occupation of a month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a reservation system but now I want to calculate what the occupation of a room in a month is.

But I'm having trouble with getting accurate results because if a reservations start date is at f.e. 28 december and ends on the 3rd of january it will count or 6 days or none at all depending on the query.

It should count just 3 days since only 3 of the 6 days of the reservation are in december

```
SELECT 
    room_id, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) as days 
FROM reservations 
WHERE 
    start_time >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' 
    AND end_time < '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY room_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition in the `WHERE` clause is wrong because it will reject reservations where `start_date` and `end_date` are not both in the same month:

```
SELECT 
  room_id, 
  SUM(DATEDIFF(
    LEAST(dropoff_time, '2019-12-31 23:59:59'),
    GREATEST(pickup_time, '2019-12-01 00:00:00')
  ) + 1) as days 
FROM reservations 
WHERE 
  (pickup_time >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' AND pickup_time < '2020-01-01 00:00:00')
  OR
  (dropoff_time >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' AND dropoff_time < '2020-01-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY room_id
```

Comment: Actually i've just ran these queries but it seems like reservations that have start dates in 1 month end in the other are still not being summed up

Comment: Post sample data and expected results in text format to test.

Comment: Hi forpas [sample data and expected results and also what i got](https://hastebin.com/sacukuvisa.css)

thank you for helping me out by the way

Comment: For room_id=4 why do you expect 7? You should expect 3.

Comment: Oh yeah i changed dates to start_date = 2019-11-01 00:00:00
end_date = 2019-12-01 00:00:00 to go with this sample data but i forgot to mention it sorry

Comment: So now my result is like the one before but +1
[result](https://hastebin.com/ekisexavok.cpp)

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cqJ7iqead2ZgFzVdGRErV7/1

Comment: And in november? then it returns this [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fpUk2aS9bkFiRJ76AhuCWQ/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fpUk2aS9bkFiRJ76AhuCWQ/0)

Comment: There is no 31st of November: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fpUk2aS9bkFiRJ76AhuCWQ/1

Comment: Hahahaha my god, thank you very much forpas. let's act like i never made that mistake

Answer (score 2):

For this query, you could use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` to adjust the month boundaries:

```
SELECT 
    room_id, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(
        LEAST('2020-01-01 00:00:00', end_time), 
        GREATEST('2019-12-01 00:00:00', start_time)
    ) as days 
FROM reservations 
WHERE 
    start_time >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' 
    AND end_time < '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY room_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the first and last dates are counted, but the logic is something like this:

```
SELECT room_id, 
       SUM(DATEDIFF(LEAST(end_time + interval 1 day, '2020-01-01'),
                    GREATEST(start_time, '2019-12-01')
                   )
          ) as days 
FROM reservations 
WHERE start_time < '2020-01-01' AND
      end_time >= '2019-12-01'   
GROUP BY room_id;
```

There are two important differences between this answer and the other answers.  The first is the logic in the `WHERE` clause.  This logic counts reservations that span the entire month of December -- starting on, say, 2019-11-15 and ending on 2020-01-15.

The second is adding 1 day to `end_time`.  This is needed if you want to count a reservation from 12-01 to 12-03 as 3 days.  Otherwise, `datediff()` only returns 2 days.

I'm not 100% sure that is really the logic you want, but it is the logic that you describe in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
SELECT 
  Roomid, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(day,   StartTime, @StartDateTime))  > 0
         THEN (DATEDIFF(day,   @StartDateTime, EndTime))    
         ELSE 
           (DATEDIFF(day,   StartTime, EndTime))
 END) as Days
FROM Test2 
WHERE 
 EndTime >= @StartDateTime 
 AND EndTime < @EndDateTime
GROUP BY Roomid
```

Comment: can you try this.